# Service Fabric RemoveNode.ps1 returns Node is not found in the cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am following the instructions in the following link to remove a node:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-windows-server-add-remove-nodes/

I have downloaded the zip onto the machine that I want to remove, but when I run the command

```
.\RemoveNode.ps1 -MicrosoftServiceFabricCabFilePath .\MicrosoftAzureServiceFabric.cab -ExistingClusterConnectionEndPoint <machine in cluster>:19000
```

It always returns:

```
Removing Service Fabric Node...
Remove node to existing cluster failed with exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Node is not found in the cluster
   at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<RemoveNodeAsyncInternal>d__46.MoveNext()
```

I have also tried just simply running the commands that exist in that script, but the same issue happens:

```
    Connect-ServiceFabricCluster "<machine in cluster>:19000"
    Get-ServiceFabricNode
    Remove-ServiceFabricNode -PreviewMode $true
```

I have tried stopping the service and then running the above, same issue. I have also tried many variations of deactivating, but all result in the same issue.

Thanks in advance for the help!